# Counting duplicate values in a sequence - for football scores

Tags: microsoft-excel

I currently have a column of values like the one below, listing the outcomes of football matches.

```
Lost
Lost
Lost
Won
Drew
Drew
Won
Won
```

Using this formula, I've been able to calculate where a sequence is repeated - so for the list above, there are three 'Lost' in a row.

```
=IF(A2=A1,B1+1,1)
```

However, I'd like to calculate where the value is either 'Drew' or 'Won' (thereby showing the number of rows without a "lost" appearing. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to `count` (as the title of your question indicates) or find the location (as you mention in the question)? Can you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1381646/edit) to show us the expected outcome?

Comment: If you just want a total count, then something like `=COUNTA(A1:A8)-COUNTIF(A1:A8,"Lost")`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a module sub that looks through column A until encountering a blank cell and prints the largest non-"Lost" streak to cell B1.

```
Sub CountNonLoss()

Dim nonloss As Integer
Dim LongestStreak As Integer
Dim Val
Dim streak As New Collection
nonloss = 0
LongestStreak = 0

Range("A1").Select

  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    If ActiveCell.Value <> "Lost" Then
       nonloss = nonloss + 1
    Else
       streak.Add nonloss
       nonloss = 0
    End If
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Loop

  For Each Val In streak
    If Val > LongestStreak Then
       LongestStreak = Val
    End If
  Next Val

Range("B1").Value = LongestStreak
End Sub
```